# Can't compare value from text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am problem with using === to compare string
I get whole data from text file and split value line by line with ('\n')
like readLine() in java 
and want to find string "SECTION"  but can't find.

when i put

```
if(contents[i] === "SECTION") {
    alert("This is section");
}
```

no alert! I am sure text file have word "SECTION"

but

```
if (contents[i].match("SECTION))
```

is work.

any suggestion ? thanks

---

javascript

```
function readFile (evt) {
var files = evt.target.files;
    if (files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
            var file = files[i];           
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() { 
                var contents = [];
                contents = this.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
                        if(contents[i] === "SECTION") {
                            alert("This is section");
                        }
                        document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML +=contents[i];
                    }
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `==` to compare, `===` not only compares the value, additionally it goes deeper and checks if the "types" matching. Don't know why they should differ, but you can check it with `typeof <varname>`

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach I think since they are using `.readAsText`, it's safe to assume everything in `contents` is strings, let alone the fact that `contents` was created by `split`, which is a string method and will produce an array of strings. So it probably wouldn't hurt to use `===` but wouldn't necessarily help. Also, `===` does type checking first, then compares values if the types are the same (not the reverse)...it doesn't bother with type coercion.

Comment: ouch... yeah you're right (+1). Sorry, it's 7 am and my coffee is just boiling ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of weirdness in your code, but:

```
var contents = [];
contents = this.result.split("\n");
```

There is no need for both lines, the second assignment overwrites the first, so:

```
var contents = this.result.split("\n");
```

.

```
for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    if(contents[i] === "SECTION") {
```

There is no need for `===` here, though I guess it doesn't hurt. It may be that there is whitespace around the comparison text, so you might consider either removing whitespace or using a regular expression instead, e.g.:

```
var re = /^\s*SECTION\s*$/;
```

to match the word "SECTION" with optionally any amount of whitespace before and after. If you just want a line that contains the character sequence SECTION, then:

```
var re = /\s*SECTION\s*/;
```

and ignoring case:

```
var re = /\s*SECTION\s*/i;
```

whatever. Then use the [`test`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) method like:

```
for  ( ... ) {
    if (re.test(contents[i])) {
       /* found a section */
```